# SIM968 Library for KiCAD

Tags: kicad

I want to add the component SIM968 GSM/GNSS Module to my KiCAD project. But I am not able to download any library from anywhere like I found one for the SIM908 while I was using Eagle.

Any advices as to how I could find a solution to my problem?

Comment: You should seriously consider creating the library. You'll need that knowledge sooner or later... I personally quite enjoy the process :)

Comment: this is the response I was scared to recieve. But since I got it already, OK I will take your word for it. 

That means I will have to lean how to create a foot print as well as a schematic component. Am I right?

could you please recommend a reliable source for me to start learning how to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend creating your own. I learnt how to do it by following [this small tutorial project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTyi3RvNoB0&list=PLy2022BX6Esr6yxwDzhqYZyuuenJE2s5B) by Contextual Electronics.